# Difference between response.setHeader and response.writeHead?

Tags: javascript, node.js

In my application, I have my Nodejs server send a JSON response. I found two ways to do this but I'm not sure what the differences are.

One way is

```
var json = JSON.stringify(result.rows);
response.writeHead(200, {'content-type':'application/json', 'content-length':Buffer.byteLength(json)}); 
response.end(json);
```

And my other way is

```
var json = JSON.stringify(result.rows);
response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
response.end(json);
```

Both ways work and I'm just wondering what the difference is between the two and when I should use one over the other.

Comment: Docs? http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_writehead_statuscode_reasonphrase_headers

Comment: Sure, I have read the docs. But my knowledge on response headers are limited and just wanted to mainly know when I should use one way over the other.

Comment: When you want to set a single header without setting statusCode use `setHeader`, when you want to set statusCode and a bunch of headers (optionally) use `writeHead`. (c) Captain Obvious

Comment: People on S.O. are so cruel with their downvotes. I see absolutely nothing wrong with this question.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

`response.setHeader()` allows you only to set a **singular** header.

`response.writeHead()` will allow you to set pretty much everything about the response head including status code, content, and **multiple** headers.

Consider the NodeJS docs:

[**response.setHeader(name, value)**](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_setheader_name_value)

> Sets a single header value for implicit headers. If this header already exists in the to-be-sent headers, its value will be replaced. Use an array of strings here to send multiple headers with the same name.

```
var body = "hello world";
response.setHeader("Content-Length", body.length);
response.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
response.setHeader("Set-Cookie", "type=ninja");
response.status(200);
```

[**response.writeHead(statusCode[, statusMessage][, headers]))**](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_writehead_statuscode_statusmessage_headers)

> Sends a response header to the request. The status code is a 3-digit HTTP status code, like `404`. The last argument, `headers`, are the response headers. Optionally one can give a human-readable `statusMessage` as the second argument.

```
var body = "hello world";
response.writeHead(200, {
    "Content-Length": body.length,
    "Content-Type": "text/plain",
    "Set-Cookie": "type=ninja"
});
```

Comment: This answer is guiding me into the direction of understanding it a bit more. Thank you for this. As you can see, both methods looks almost identical in code, thus causing my confusion. So I just wasn't understanding why I would use setHeader over writeHead if at the basic level, they're both doing the same thing.

Comment: res.statusCode = 200; not  response.status(200);

Tested in Node.js v5

Comment: @Bhaveshkumar I'm seeing [`res.status()`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.status) as valid and in the documentation.

Comment: `response.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/html"});` once header is set using writeHead it cannot be changed again
this will also override headers set by setHeader

https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v13.x/docs/api/http.html#http_response_writehead_statuscode_statusmessage_headers

Comment: The other thing you don't mention here is that once you call `response.writeHead()`, the headers are sent and you can no longer set any more headers.   Whereas `response.setHeader()` just configures what headers will be sent when they are sent sometime in the future and you can continue to set or modify headers until they are actually sent.