# Sending headers from node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In Node JS Express, I have a API called download. This returns a buffer to the calling application along with a header called status (which is a Javascript object).

I am sending the buffer as the response body from the Node and would like to send the status as a custom header.

This is how my response looks like

```
response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');

    if(responseBody instanceof Buffer) {
         var status = JSON.stringify(responseHeaders.status);
         console.log('Status is '+status); //Status is printed correctly here as a Javascript object

        response.writeHead(responseStatusCode, responseHeaders);
        response.end(responseBody);
        console.log('Buffer sent')
    }
```

I am calling this from Postman. When the response reaches Postman, in the headers tab, status is shown as [object Object].

```
status --> [object Object]
```

I am stringifying it before sending the headers to the client, So why do I see object in the response header.

Comment: does setHeader accept json as a param?

Comment: better go with a string

Comment: Wouldn't JSON.stringify convert it to a String? It's first converted to a String and then that String is set as a header.

Comment: JSON.stringify should convert it to a javascript object, thus the [object Object]

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. Did a toString() while setting the header but with the same result. response.setHeader('status', status.toString());

Comment: try url encoding the value

Comment: Still the same result with response.setHeader('status', encodeURI(status));

Comment: strange ...doesn't `response.writeHead `overrides the `setHead()`

Comment: You may like to have a look http://stackoverflow.com/a/28094490/3461055

Comment: I have got rid of setHeader now, just doing a writeHead (updated the post as well). However, result is exactly the same.

Comment: Do it the other way around.  Leave setHeader and remove writeHead.  responseHeaders still has the object version.

Comment: Leaving the setHeader and removing writeHead solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
res.statusCode = status;
return res.json(responsebody);
```